# BackboneJS - set the 'el' of the parent/inherited view

Tags: backbone.js

So I'm trying to abstract my `<table>` work in Backbone, so I created a 'table view' which extends my 'base view'. So when I need a new table, I can just extend the 'table view' and hopefully point the 'table view' to the DOM element I want it to render in, ie. like so:

```
app.Views.quotesList = app.Views.table.extend({
    template: '#tmpl-table',


    initialize: function(){
        this.collection = new Backbone.Collection([
          {name: "Tim", age: 5},
          {name: "Ben", age: 26},
          {name: "Rob", age: 55}
        ]);
    },

    render: function() {
        var that = this;
        var template = Handlebars.compile( $(this.template).html() );
        $(this.el).html(template({id: 'quotes'}));

        this.table = this.$('#table-quotes');
        this.thead = this.table.find('thead tr');
        this.tbody = this.table.find('tbody');

        var template = Handlebars.compile( $('#table-heading').html() );
        that.thead.append(template(that.collection.first().toJSON()));

        var template = Handlebars.compile( $('#table-row').html() );
        that.collection.each(function(model){
            that.tbody.append(template(model.toJSON()));
        });
        return this;
    },

});
```

I'd like to move most of this generic code to a table view:

```
app.Views.table = app.Views.base.extend({

        initialize: function(){

        }

    });
```

So how would I go about telling the 'table view' what element to render into from the 'quotesList view'?

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm misunderstanding what you're after here, you should still just be able to pass in `el` when you construct your child view, even if it inherits from the table view:

```
new app.Views.quotesList({ el: $('#foo') })
```

As long as you pass it into the initializer, it'll be set by the time you call `render()` or anything else that uses it, even if `render()` is defined by the parent (table) View.

Comment: Thanks, but what I need to do, is pass the 'el' to the parent view? or am I overthinking this?

Comment: I think you are overthinking it.

Comment: If it's not working for you, it could be that it's because the parent `initialize()` isn't being called (since you've overwritten it in the child). Try adding an `options` arg to your `quotesList` `initialize()` function and calling `app.Views.table.prototype.initialize.call(options)` at the beginning of it.

Comment: Now that I think about it, though, you really shouldn't have to call `prototype.initialize`. It should just work without that.